# Script para consultar IP externo

Tags: php, python, linux, windows, ip

Como posso obter o endereço de `IP` da pessoa que logou no meu sistema?

Procurei no Google e tudo que encontro são consultas em sites terceiros (https://api.ipify.org/, http://ident.me/, entre outros) que trazem o `IP`.

Alguém conhece algum link ou algum script(PHP, Python,...) que faça isso?

Answer (score 2):

No link que você postou https://api.ipify.org/  adicionando `?format=json` ele te retorna o `Ip`no formato `Json`. O link completo você pode visualizar [aqui](https://api.ipify.org/?format=json).

Você pode obter o `Ip`usando a função `getJSON`do Jquery.

Segue exemplo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function (data) {
                alert(data.ip);
            });
        });
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi isso da seguinte maneira

```
function getIP() {
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) {
        $proxy = '';
        if($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) {
            $proxy = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } else {
            $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }

        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    } else {
        if($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
    }

    if (empty($proxy)) {
        return $ip;
    } else {
        return $proxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recomendo usar `empty` e todas verificações de variáveis

Answer (score 0):

Esses links estão a retornar o ip que a sua maquina esta a usar (cliente)

para obter o mesmo ip através de php pode usar este código:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Se quiser uma função que retorne um IP com um grau de certeza maior, tem esta função:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { 
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { 
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; }
else { echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; }

?>
```